# android on back button click action

Tags: android

I have a single activity and 4 menu. suppose I click on home menu and add a fragment lets say FragmentA and then from FragmentA I add another fragment say FragmentB now when I press back button it returns back to HomeFragment instead of FragmentA. why is so?

Comment: when you are adding fragment just add one function and it works on back press . activity.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(CONTAINER_ID,FRAGMENT).addToBackStack(null/FRAGmentName).commit()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it Using `popBackStack();` like

```
  override fun onBackPressed() {
            val manager: FragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
            if(manager.backStackEntryCount > 0){
                manager.popBackStack()
            }else{
                super.onBackPressed()
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The back button is used to come back to previous Activity only not Fragment.